# In ASP.NET MVC Radio buttons checked changed event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC4 I have two radio buttons rb1 and return and two text boxes  and txt2...

How can I disable my text box txt2 whenever rb2 was checked?

Here is my code:

below code may in html helpers or  html tags

```
    <input type="radio" id="rb1" value="r1" name="jrn" />

    <input type="radio" id="rb2" value="r2" name="jrn" checked="checked"/>

     <input type="text" name="txt1" id="Ret" value="v1" />

    <input type="text" name="txt2" id="Dep" value="v2"   />
```

Comment: Why are you using webforms controls in an MVC project?

Comment: Could you please check it now ,I have edited actual format

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   $('#rb2').change(function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
          $("#txt2").prop("disabled", true);
      }
      else
      {
         $("#txt2").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**How can you use webforms control in MVC!!!!!!**

**Big Big issue**, you are not allowed to do it.

After updating your code, you can use Javascript to do the needful
here is the code

```
function disablefield()
{
    if ( document.admin.customerInfo_0.checked = true)
         document.admin.txtPhoneNumber.value = enabled
          elseif (admin.customerInfo_1.value="yes")
            document.admin.txtLastName.value.enabled=false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#rb2').change(function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
          $("#txt2").attr("disabled", "disabled");     
      }
      else
      {
          $("#txt2").removeAttr("disabled");             
      }
});
```

Comment: You've got the disabling backwards.